# Get access to the logger object when not in a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a few business classes that represents logic of my application, I want to write logs from this classes, just like in a controller, how do I achieve reference to the logger.

If you want to tell me send it in constructor please don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you know that your object will be in the Rails environment-- a service object, for example, instantiated and called from a controller --then you can use `Rails.logger` to get the same logger referenced by the `logger` method from within a controller or model.

For example, from `app/services/payments.rb`:

```
rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  error = e.message
  Rails.logger.error "Stripe card error for account #{@account}, error #{e}"
```

Answer (score -3):

I am confused...I just use e.g.

```
logger.info("in model")
```

or

```
logger.info("in controller")
```

in my models and controllers all the time, this being rails 3.2/ruby 1.9.3. Of course I might be misunderstanding something completely.

Comment: "misunderstanding something completely." yes.  the question specifies logging from a PORO business class outside of the controller.